# Add new column of String to StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I want to display guitar tablature as String, however I have a problem with showing tab as string.
Wanted look:

```
--------
--------
--------
--------
--------
3-1-2--3
```

What I get is:

```
-
-
-
-
-
3-
-
-
-
-
1-
```

Imagine every column as one fragment. As I am going through fragments, I'm adding a new column for each fragment, however I cannot add a new column to string, it just goes to the new line. Does anyone have any better idea how to solve this issue, or a fix for this print issue?
Thank you in advance for your time and effort!

Comment: Share code what you have tried

Comment: I bet you are using `println` which inserts a line break after each text. Edit your question to add your code

Comment: you seem to be printing first all the first chars of the rows, then the second chars of the rows, you should be printing the entire rows

Comment: My advise would be create a method that will prepare the corresponding row & then print it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the response, I succeed as V M said. I prepared each row first, then I printed all at once, works like a charm.

```
public static String parseSongToTab() {
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (Fragment fragment : loadedSong.getFragments()) {
  GuitarString gs = GuitarString.valueOf(fragment.getString().toUpperCase());
  createTabColumn(gs, fragment.getFret());
}
stringBuilder.append(stringBuilderHighE).append("\n")
    .append(stringBuilderB).append("\n")
    .append(stringBuilderG).append("\n")
    .append(stringBuilderD).append("\n")
    .append(stringBuilderA).append("\n")
    .append(stringBuilderLowE);
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

}
CreateTab:

```
private static void createTabColumn(GuitarString guitarString, Integer fret) {
switch (guitarString) {
  case LOW_E:
    stringBuilderLowE.append(fret);
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  case A:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append(fret);
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  case D:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append(fret);
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  case G:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append(fret);
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  case B:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append(fret);
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  case HIGH_E:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append(fret);
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
  default:
    stringBuilderLowE.append("-");
    stringBuilderA.append("-");
    stringBuilderD.append("-");
    stringBuilderG.append("-");
    stringBuilderB.append("-");
    stringBuilderHighE.append("-");
    addSpaceForEverySecond();
    break;
}
```

}